# icmp response for ip options

Tags: python-3.x, ip, scapy, icmp

How should I do it?

I have written a new IP Option field in the scapy 2.4 source code (scapy.layers.inet).

```
class IPOption_Ex(IPOption):
name = "IP Option Ex"
copy_flag = 1
option = 26
fields_desc = [_IPOption_HDR,
               ByteField("op1", 16),
               ShortField("op2", 0),
               ShortField("op3", 0),
               IPField("originator_ip", "0.0.0.0"),
               LongField("op4", 0)]
```

It is just L3 level option so it does not involve TCP or UDP. Whenever the destination receives the new IP Option (say 26) I want a response ICMP packet (type 45). Say the response ICMP packet has four fields: 1.Type 2.Code 3.Checksum 4.source IP address. (scapy.layers.inet)

```
class ICMP(Packet):
name = "ICMP"
fields_desc = [ ByteEnumField("type",8, icmptypes),
                MultiEnumField("code",0, icmpcodes, depends_on=lambda pkt:pkt.type,fmt="B"),
                XShortField("chksum", None),
                ConditionalField(IPField("originator_ip","0.0.0.0"), lambda pkt:pkt.type==45)]
```

Now what I don't understand how to write code in python/scapy to generate ICMP type-45 response packet from the destination and where to write in scapy source code?

Comment: Isn’t it just `ICMP(type=45)...` ?

Comment: @Cukic0d No, the host which sent out say send(IP(src="ip of host" options = 'IPOption(26)))' in Scapy is not receiving ICMP(type=45)

Comment: Sorry I don’t understand your question. Please try to correct your English “It is just L3 level option so it does not involve TCP or UDP” ?! “where to write in Scapy source code” (you want to edit scapy’s source code ?!)

Comment: okay. The IP option which I defined above does not involve any transport level protocol. In Scapy if I want to send an IP packet like `send(IP(src="ip of host" options = 'IPOption(26)))` then I want to receive an `ICMP(type = 45)` response packet. So should I make changes in scapy source code or write another script or make changes in OS stack I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You just need

```
IPOption_Ex.register_variant()
```

You'll then have

```
IP(options=[IPOption(option=26)])
```

working